# display an alert when the button is click in javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Good day. newbie here... my code is working will.. my problem is after clicking the button twice or more than that the alert text doesn't show again.. what I want to do is to display the text if I click the button once or many time without refreshing the page.. here is my code...

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Ajax post 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $(".submit").click(function() { 

var message = $("textarea#l_message").val(); 

 jQuery.ajax({ 
 type: "POST", 
 url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin/user_data_submit", 
 dataType: 'json', 
 data: {l_message: message}, 
 success: function(res) { 
 if (res) 
 { 
  // Show Entered Value 
 jQuery("div#msg").show(); 
 jQuery("div#msg").html('Update Successfully!'); 
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#msg").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
  });
}, 5000);
} else {
 } 
} 
 }); 
  return false; 
 }); 
}); 

 </script>
```

**my form**

```
<?php echo form_open();
                echo form_label('Librarians Message');
                ?>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="the_librarian" id="l_message">  </textarea>

                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Update',"class='btn btn-success navbar-btn submit'");?>
                <?php echo form_close();?>

 <div id="msg" style="color: green;">
 </div>
```

the alert message will close after 5sec then after that if I click the button again the alert message doesn't show. I want to show that message again even I click the button multiple times... sorry for the Grammar,..

help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> $(this).remove();

is removing the entire #msg div from the DOM, so it isn't there to be shown again. You could use

> $(this).hide();

instead.

Also, opacity is remaining at 0, so change:

> jQuery("div#msg").hide();

to

> jQuery("div#msg").hide().css('opacity','1');

Comment: thanks for the reply sir John but even I change that into $(this).hide(); does not show again after the second click of the button...

Comment: It looks like maybe the .slideUp() is changing the position of the #msg div. You might need to reposition the element to its original position after the hide() so it is available to be shown again in its intended location. EDIT: No that's not it. It shouldn't maintain its new position after the slideup()

Comment: OK one more thing, the opacity may be remaining at 0 and the show() function does not effect opacity. Try to change  jQuery("div#msg").show(); 
to  jQuery("div#msg").show().css('opacity','1');

Comment: so thats the effect of using the fadeTo?

Comment: yes, fade to is taking the CSS opacity down to 0 and nothing is in place to get it back to 1 to be shown again.

Comment: sir its showing again but not in the right time,. the text display if I click the button many times..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102502/discussion-between-mgb-c-and-john-fable).